# Why does running my Python script start taking a screenshot?

Tags: python

I'm writing a script in Python, but when I attempt to run it a cross cursor appears and lets me take screenshots. But that's not part of my program, and the rest of the script never executes at all!

The minimal code that produces this behavior is:

```
import fiona
import scipy
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking / what's going on. It looks like you just import two packages. What's going wrong after you import the packages in the rest of your script?

Comment: That's one hell of a side-effect for a couple of imports.  Especially of modules that possess no such capability.  I almost don't believe it.  Anyway, your question isn't answerable in its current state.  The only thing to be said is "those modules don't do that."

Comment: Since neither of those packages does anything related to screenshots, and since Windows (your statistically-likely OS) only pops crosshairs ("cross cursor") for screenshots when using the Snipping Tool, I'd say this is environment-related, and you won't fix it by editing a Python module.

Comment: I'm in Ubuntu 15.04. And I really don't know what to ask, because I don't see any sense in that behaviour...

Comment: Does Ubuntu have screenshot functionality like that? If so, you might want to add the `Ubuntu` tag to your question.

Comment: This question seems to reappear once in a while https://stackoverflow.com/q/45849176/1328439

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a known issue which regularly happens to some.

Without a `python` shebang line the script is treated as a shell script. And line `import module` is treated as a command to run `import` application, which is present on your system (part of ImageMagick, I guess) and makes a screenshot saving it to the specified file.

Comment: Stumbled here because I had a typo... `#/usr/bin/env python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It got solved by adding the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

but I really don't understand why...

Comment: Bash import takes a screen shot.

Comment: @warvarluc explains it in his answer. On the command line, type `man import` and you'll get a description of the linux `import` command. Without the shebang, your shell thinks its another shell script.