# Just writing 'import' in a python script breaks my mouse cursor forcing a hard reset

Tags: python, debian

I'm totally baffled by this.. Trying to code a python script on my Debian Stretch system but after running a 4 lined script my mouse cursor would turn into a cross and blocking any click actions from working and forcing me to hard reset the system by holding the off button!

I tested a few times and found out that my script just needs to contain an import for it to break, nothing else - literally a one-lined:

```
import pxssh
```

And run

```
./bug.py
```

System broken.  Mouse cursor looks like a cross and cannot click anywhere. Hard reset required.

I found someone else with what appears to be the exact same issue, there's an uploaded image of it but I don't know if it was python causing it for him/her. https://askubuntu.com/questions/918261/why-does-my-cursor-keep-changing-to-a-black-cross-and-how-do-i-revert-it

If I use my keyboard and re-run it again, I get this error:

```
import-im6.q16: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9182.
```

Comment: That *specific* import, or just any import at all? Does `import os` have the same effect?

Comment: Hi there,  I've amended my question with an error message relating to mouse on re-run.  But, yeah any import will break it, it's not specific.

Comment: How about a script that doesn't have `import`? Does that also hang your system?

Comment: This sounds like you did something horrible to something you shouldn't have touched because you didn't realize you shouldn't have touched it.

Comment: Sound like that, but nope - this is a brand new install last night.   Strangely, if I put 'import os' in there was well as another one the same issue happens with the mouse but after two clicks it changes back again and works and I can click.  So confused by all of this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're not running Python! You're accidentally running this as a shell script. Run it as

```
python bug.py
```

or include the shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Currently, you seem to be running a [completely unrelated program named `import`](https://ss64.com/bash/import.html), designed for screen capture.

Comment: PMSL.  Damn I'm a numpty. Well done on spotting the obvious.

Comment: I tried to downvote my own question, but it doesn't let me do that.

Comment: This could happend also if you mis-type the shebang like `#/usr/bin/python` for example even and the file is executable

Answer (score 7):

This has just happened to me, and without this thread I would never have found the cause. I just would like to add that you can stop the 'import' program by running:

```
pkill -9 import
```

And that should fix everything.